# A powerful affix riddle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix is better served cold, and with friends
> My infix is bigger than PETA's smaller brother
> My suffix is a fire lizard, devoid of Arabian peace
> **Who am I?**

Comment: No, "smaller brother" is not a typo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your name is:

> **ALEXANDER**

*My prefix is better served cold, and with friends*

> Your prefix is **ALE**, a drink often served cold in a pub or bar on a social occasion.

*My infix is bigger than PETA's smaller brother*

> Your infix is **EXA**, the [metric prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) for one quintillion (10^18), larger than one quadrillion (represented by 'peta', the lower-case *little brother* of the upper-case PETA) by a factor of one thousand.

*My suffix is a fire lizard, devoid of Arabian peace*

> Your suffix is **ANDER**, derived from SALAMANDER (a fire lizard) without SALAM ('peace' in Arabic).

Given the title and its emphasis on *power*, it is quite possible that you are:

> the ancient ruler and leader, **[Alexander the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_the_Great)**.